# How to code randomized battles for RPG

Tags: android

I'm having trouble understanding how to add randomized combat to a text based rpg I am making. I've seen some videos on youtube about textbased games but they want the user to type. My user will only be typing to name their character. I will have a db broken into multiple tables. Locations, actions, equipment, npcs, events etc. Ideally combat would flow like this...

```
Attacker roles random int + attack chance = attack
defender roles random int + dodge chance = dodge
attack - dodge = hit
if hit > 0 roll damage
role random int + base damage = damage
role random int for crit
if crit < crit chance then damage * 2 = damage2
damage2 - defenders armor rating int = applieddamage
defenders hp int - applieddamage
```

Any mock code or tutorials you know about would really help.

Comment: You've already written pseudo-code for your combat system. What do you need? How to get a random int in Java? You've only tagged this question Android. What does this question have to do with Android? You mention videos that aren't helpful because they expect the user to type, but what does the UI have to do with coding up the combat system of the game? Your question is extremely vague and does not seem well thought out.

Comment: I guess the vague and not well thought out questions is what I get when I'm working late on this. I have a general idea of how it would flow but really just having trouble connecting the final dots. Was hoping someone may post what they have used before so I can see what a finished product looks like.